# Problema con herencia en Python

Tags: python, herencia

Estoy empezando con Python y me cuesta un poco ver el tema de la herencia en Python.
He creado dos clases, una rectángulo y otra cuadrado que hereda de de Rectángulo.

Código:

```
class Rectangle:

  def __init__(self, width, height):
    self.__width= width
    self.__height = height

  def set_width(self, width):
    self.__width = width
  def set_height(self, height):
    self.__height = height
  def get_area(self):
    return self.__width * self.__height
  def get_perimeter(self):
    return (2*self.__width) + (2* self.__height)
  def get_diagonal(self):
    return (self.__width ** 2 + self.__height ** 2) ** .5
  def get_picture(self):
    if(self.__width > 50 or self.__height > 50):
      return 'Too big for picture.'
    else:
      dibuja = ''
      for i in range(self.__height):
        dibuja += '*' * (self.__width) + '\n'
    return dibuja
  def get_amount_inside(self, figura):
    return ''
  def __str__(self):
    return 'Rectangle(width=' + str(self.__width) + ', height=' + str(self.__height) + ')'



class Square(Rectangle):
  def __init__(self, width, side =0):
    super().__init__(width, width)
  def set_side(self, side):
    self.__side = side
  def __str__(self):
    return 'Square(side=' + str(Rectangle.__width) + ')'

sq = Square(5)
sq.set_width(4)
actual = str(sq)
```

Mi problema surge cuando llamo a la función __str().
Cuando creo el objeto Cuadrado, llamo al constructor de rectángulo pasándole la altura y la anchura en un único parámetro. Después de modificar el valor de la variable width, a través de la función set_width del constructor, no sé cómo acceder ahora a dicha variable.

El objetivo es conseguir acceder a la variable width del objeto padre. He probado a hacerlo así. Rectangle.__width, pero me dice que dicha variable no está definida.
No entiendo por qué, pues supuestamente me refiero a la variable del padre, creada al construir.

También se me ha ocurrido, intentar esto:

return 'Square(side=' + str(super().__width) + ')'

Cómo puedo acceder al valor de dicha variable?

Comment: Creo que para heredar los atributos del padre necesitas incluir un super().__init__()

Comment: En mi constructor, ya lo tengo incluido. Te refieres a eso? super().__init__(width, width)

Comment: Si, pero no le pases los parámetros

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Lo primero es reducir el código al mínimo para estudiar el problema sin tanta paja molida:

```
class Rectangle:
  def __init__(self, width, height):
    self.__width= width
    self.__height = height

class Square(Rectangle):
  def __init__(self, width, side =0):
    super().__init__(width, width)
  def __str__(self):
    return 'Square(side=' + str(Rectangle.__width) + ')'

sq = Square(5)
print(sq)
```

produce el error:

```
    return 'Square(side=' + str(Rectangle.__width) + ')'
AttributeError: type object 'Rectangle' has no attribute '_Square__width'
```

**Atributos de clase**

Lo primeros es reemplazar `Rectangle.__width` por `self.__width`, dado que los atributos del objeto padre también lo son del objeto hijo.

Debes considerar que `Rectangle.__width` se refiere a un **atributo de clase**, es decir, a un valor compartido por todos los objetos tipo `Rectangle`.

La clase `Rectangle` no tiene ningún atributo de clase. Un atributo de clase se declara fuera de cualquier `def`, así

```
class Rectangle:
    unidad_medida = "cms"
    def __init__(self, width, height):
    ...
```

de modo que `Rectangle.unidad_medida` da por resultado "cms".

**Name mangling**

Volviendo a lo nuestro: el problema es que usas doble barra para definir los atributos. Cuando dices

```
self.__width = width
```

le estas pidiendo a Python que oculte `__width`, que lo haga un atributo privado. Lo que hace Python es transformar (mangle) el nombre, para que nadie más lo pueda usar, que es precisamente lo que pasa aquí. En esta situación, el nombre real del atributo pasa a ser `_Rectangle__width`.

**Solución**

Cambia las doble barra

```
self.__width = width
```

por barra simple (o eliminalas)

```
self._width = width
```

Los nombres con una sola barra son nombres como cualquier otro. La barra simplemente es una forma de documentación, que dice "por favor, soy privado, haz cuenta de que no existo".

El código que entonces así:

```
class Rectangle:
  unidad_medida = "cms"
  def __init__(self, width, height):
    self._width= width
    self._height = height

class Square(Rectangle):
  def __init__(self, width, side =0):
    super().__init__(width, width)
  def __str__(self):
    return 'Square(side=' + str(self._width) + Rectangle.unidad_medida + ')'

sq = Square(5)
print(sq)
s2 = Square(10)
print(s2)
```

y produce:

```
Square(side=5cms)
Square(side=10cms)
```

Comment: Gracias por la respuesta. Evidentemente, no entendía para que sirve el __ en las variables y funciones.

Comment: A cualquier se le pasa, y lo aprende cuando fallan :-)